# How can you map a binding with a pipe?

Tags: vim, neovim

e.g. I want to map

```
nnoremap <a-v> :vs | term<cr>
```

but vim is interpreting this as `nnoremap <a-v> :vs` followed by the separate command `term<cr>`. How do I declare the the associativity here? Using eval and execute do not work.

Answer (score 2):

I asked too soon, figured it out a minute later: you simply escape the pipe:

```
nnoremap <a-v> :vs \| term<CR>
```

Comment: Or use `<Bar>` instead, which is more commonly used; see `:help map-bar`.

Comment: What about backticks or dollar? I need to include another command's output as parameters for the command receving the pipe.